# Plot density curve of mixture of two normal distribution

Tags: r, loops, plot

I am rather new to R and could use some basic help. I'd like to generate sums of two normal random variables (variance = 1 for each) as their means move apart and plot the results. The basic idea: if the means are sufficiently far apart, the distribution will be bimodal. Here's the code I'm trying:

```
x <- seq(-3, 3, length=500)
for(i in seq(0, 3, 0.25)) {
y <- dnorm(x, mean=0-i, sd=1)
z <- dnorm(x, mean=0+i, sd=1)
plot(x,y+z, type="l", xlim=c(-3,3))
}
```

Several questions:

1. Are there better ways to do this?
2. I'm only getting one PDF on my plot. How can I put multiple PDFs on the same plot?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I hardly see the point of ggplot2 if you use plot.

Comment: I think there's a problem because if you look at `summary(y)` and `summary(z)` they have the same mean, range, etc

Comment: Fair, no need for ggplot2. Shouldn't y have mean -0.25, -0.5, -0.75 etc. and z mean 0.25, 0.5, 0.75... as the loop goes? If not, I welcome any suggestions to fix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not difficult to do this using basic **R** features. We first define a function `f` to compute the density of this mixture of normal:

```
## `x` is an evaluation grid
## `dev` is deviation of mean from 0
f <- function (x, dev) {
  (dnorm(x, -dev) + dnorm(x, dev)) / 2
  }
```

Then we use `sapply` to loop through various `dev` to get corresponding density:

```
## `dev` sequence to test
dev <- seq(0, 3, 0.25)
## evaluation grid; extending `c(-1, 1) * max(dev)` by 4 standard deviation
x <- seq(-max(dev) -4, max(dev) + 4, by = 0.1)
## density matrix
X <- sapply(dev, f, x = x)
## a comment on 2022-07-31: X <- outer(x, dev, f)
```

Finally we use `matplot` for plotting:

```
matplot(x, X, type = "l", lty = 1)
```

[image]

---

**Explanation of `sapply`:**

During `sapply`, `x` is not changed, while we pick up and try one element of `dev` each iteration. It is like

```
X <- matrix(0, nrow = length(x), ncol = length(dev))
for (i in 1:length(dev)) X[, i] <- f(x, dev[i])
```

`matplot(x, X)` will plot columns of `X` one by one, against `x`.

**A comment on 2022-07-31:** Just use `outer`. Here are more examples:

- [Run a function of 2 arguments over a span of parameter values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51275138/4891738)
- [Plot of a Binomial Distribution for various probabilities of success in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444739/4891738)