# Run a function of 2 arguments over a span of parameter values in R

Tags: r, function, matrix, sequence

I wish to run a function of 2 arguments over a span of parameter values. For example, given the following function:

```
myfunction <- function(arg1, arg2)
{
 res <- arg1 * 0.1 + arg2  
}
```

I want to compute the results for all combinations of `arg1 = seq(1, 10, 1)` and `arg2 = seq(20, 100, 20)` and then shape the them into a `length(arg1)` x `length(arg2)` matrix. What is an efficient way to set this up?

Comment: R novice here, can you give me an example of outer function? Thanks.

Comment: can myfunction be a fairly complicated simulation function? Also, if myfunction takes in more than 2 arguments, how do I specify seq(1,10,1) is arg1 and seq(20,100,20) is arg2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`outer` function is designed for this purpose. A common usage is to produce all pixel values of a 2D image / surface. For your example `myfunction`, we can do:

```
outer(seq(1,10,1), seq(20,100,20), myfunction)
```

The function to be applied by `outer` can be complicated, as long as it is a *vectorized* function. You can check examples under `?outer`.

If you want to build `outer` into `myfunction`, we can do

```
myfunction <- function (arg1, arg2) outer(0.1 * arg1, arg2, "+")
```

where `"+"` refers to the addition function (see `?Arithmetic`) in R.