# Plot of a Binomial Distribution for various probabilities of success in R

Tags: r, plot

Is it possible to plot histogram-like bars/lines for a Binomial distributed random variable with different success probabilities next to each other in R?

The number of trials (n) and the sample space stays the same. Only the probability of success (p) is different. How has the R code to look like in order to have the bars next to each other?

Here is a small example what I mean:

```
yval <- 0:10 # sample space
plot(dbinom(yval, 10, 0.5) ~ yval, type = "h", col = "black", ylim = c(0, 0.35))
lines(dbinom(yval, 10, 1/6) ~ yval, type = "h", col = "red")
lines(dbinom(yval, 10, 0.6) ~ yval, type = "h", col = "green")
legend("topright", legend = c("p = 0.5", "p = 1/6", "p = 0.6"),
col = c("black", "red", "green"), lty = 1, cex = 0.7)
```

With this code the lines are plotted onto each other. What do I have to change here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean as follows?

[image]

You can just add a small offset to the x-values of the other histograms:

```
yval <- 0:10 # sample space
plot(dbinom(yval, 10, 0.5) ~ yval, type = "h", col = "black", ylim = c(0, 0.35))
lines(dbinom(yval, 10, 1/6) ~ I(yval + 0.1), type = "h", col = "red") # + 0.1
lines(dbinom(yval, 10, 0.6) ~ I(yval + 0.2), type = "h", col = "green") # + 0.2
legend("topright", legend = c("p = 0.5", "p = 1/6", "p = 0.6"),
col = c("black", "red", "green"), lty = 1, cex = 0.7)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! This is what I wanted. I was also initially thinking of making a small offset but I did not know how to do that. Now I know it.

Comment: Ah yes, I struggled with that before too. You need `I()`, which means 'as is'. The reason is that `+` is reserved for adding variables to the formula (e.g. `0 + x` in a regression model without intercept).

Answer (score 1):

To finish off my comment, here is what we can do with `barplot`:

```
prob <- c(0.5, 1/6, 0.6)
yval <- 0:10
Y <- t(outer(yval, prob, dbinom, size = max(yval)))
barplot(Y, names.arg = yval, beside = TRUE, col = 1:3, border = 1:3,
        legend.text = paste0("p = ", format(prob, digits = 2)))
```

[image]

Just take this as an alternative.

---

**Remark 1**

Pay attention to the use of `outer` above. Why do we have to do an extra `t()`? Can't we just do this?

```
Y <- outer(prob, yval, dbinom, size = max(yval))
```

No. This will give you lots of `NaN` with warnings. Check `args(dbinom)`. Function `dbinom` expects `yval` to be in front of `prob`.

---

**Remark 2**

Using `barplot` could easily produce some "side-effects" for you, like the following (which makes it easier for you to compare their shape).

```
prob <- c(0.5, 1/6, 0.6)
yval <- 0:10
Y <- outer(yval, prob, dbinom, size = max(yval))  ## no `t()` now
barplot(Y, names.arg = paste0("p = ", format(prob, digits = 2)), beside = TRUE)
```

With `col` argument of `barplot` unset, gray colors are used, with the darkness proportional to the height of bars.

[image]